# R: Plotting Logistic Regression in Ggplot2

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)

library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

my_data1 = data.frame(Weight =  rnorm(500,100,100), asthma = sample(c(0,1), prob = c(0.7,0.3), replace=TRUE, size= 500))
my_data2 = data.frame(Weight = rnorm(500, 200, 50),  asthma = sample(c(0,1), prob = c(0.3,0.7), replace=TRUE, size= 500))
my_data = rbind(my_data1, my_data2)
```

I fit a logistic regression model to this data:

```
# fit the logistic regression model
model <- glm(asthma ~ Weight, data = my_data, family = binomial())
```

Then, I created a data frame which contains predicted values and the corresponding confidence intervals for different values of weights:

```
# create a data frame with the predicted values and confidence intervals
preds <- data.frame(Weight = seq(min(my_data$Weight), max(my_data$Weight), length.out = 100))
preds$pred <- predict(model, preds, type = "response")
preds$upper <- predict(model, preds, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)$fit + 1.96 * predict(model, preds, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
preds$lower <- predict(model, preds, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)$fit - 1.96 * predict(model, preds, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
```

Finally, I tried to plot everything:

```
# plot the data and the model
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Weight, y = asthma)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = preds, aes(x = Weight, y = pred), color = "red") +
  geom_ribbon(data = preds, aes(x = Weight, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
  ggtitle("Logistic Regression Model with Confidence Bands")
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Error in `geom_ribbon()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
i Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'asthma' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?**

I can clearly see that a variable called "asthma" is within the data - furthermore, the following line of code runs without error:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Weight, y = asthma)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_line(data = preds, aes(x = Weight, y = pred), color = "red")
```

This being said, why is my code not running?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't redefine `y=` in the `aes` function in `geom_ribbon`, so it defaults to using the one set in `ggplot`: "asthma". I assume it should have `y=pred` like in `geom_line`?

Comment: It appears that `asthma` is a column in `mydata`, not in `preds`. Where is ‘my_data_a` defined? What happens if you add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to the `geom_ribbon` call?

Comment: @ divibisan: thank you for your reply! Do you mean like this? geom_ribbon(data = preds, aes(x = Weight, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, y= asthma), alpha = 0.2)?

Comment: @ Limey: my apologies - it was a typo (from an earlier draft)

Comment: Leave out the geom_points.

Comment: @ IRTFM: like this? ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Weight, y = asthma)) +
    geom_line(data = preds, aes(x = Weight, y = pred), color = "red") +
    geom_ribbon(data = preds, aes(x = Weight, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
    ggtitle("Logistic Regression Model with Confidence Bands")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `inherit.aes=FALSE` in geoms using `preds`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

my_data1 = data.frame(Weight =  rnorm(500,100,100), asthma = sample(c(0,1), prob = c(0.7,0.3), replace=TRUE, size= 500))
my_data2 = data.frame(Weight = rnorm(500, 200, 50),  asthma = sample(c(0,1), prob = c(0.3,0.7), replace=TRUE, size= 500))
my_data = rbind(my_data1, my_data2)

model <- glm(asthma ~ Weight, data = my_data, family = binomial())
preds <- data.frame(Weight = seq(min(my_data$Weight), max(my_data$Weight), length.out = 100))
preds$pred <- predict(model, preds, type = "response")
preds$upper <- predict(model, preds, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)$fit + 1.96 * predict(model, preds, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
preds$lower <- predict(model, preds, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)$fit - 1.96 * predict(model, preds, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Weight, y = asthma)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = preds, aes(x = Weight, y = pred), color = "red", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(data = preds, aes(x = Weight, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Logistic Regression Model with Confidence Bands")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>